# Can full CPP standard library be used if exceptions are disabled?

Tags: android, c++, libc++

I am writing native code on Android and CPP exceptions are [disabled by default](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html#xp).
I could simply enable them but I love leaving settings to default.
So I wonder if I can use all features of libc++ if exceptions are disabled?

Here is one code example:

```
std::__fs::filesystem::directory_iterator it("/does/not/exist");
```

The libc++ is compiled with exceptions. So this line will throw an exception. But I cannot catch it because my code is compiled without exceptions. My program will crash because an exception of type filesystem_error is thrown and I did not catch it:

```
terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__ndk1::__fs::filesystem::filesystem_error: filesystem error: in directory_iterator::directory_iterator(...): No such file or directory [/does/not/exist]
/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r23/toolchain/llvm-project/libcxx/../../../toolchain/llvm-project/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:72: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__ndk1::__fs::filesystem::filesystem_error: filesystem error: in directory_iterator::directory_iterator(...): No such file or directory [/does/not/exist]" failed
Aborted
```

So my question is if it is possible to use full libc++ if exceptions are disabled in my code?

Edit:
I am building a native standalone executable using ndk-build.

Comment: Only disable in the `ndk-build` (for historical reasons and can be enabled) - _"...CMake and standalone toolchains have C++ exceptions enabled by default...."_ so the default for the last few years is to have exceptions enabled.

Comment: If you disable exceptions, yes, you cannot handle exceptions. But that should have been clear?

Comment: `filesystem` has exception-less overloads taking `std::error_code`.

Comment: @RichardCritten I am building a native executable using ndk-build. Is it possible to switch to another build system so exceptions are enabled by default? If yes, how to do this?

Comment: Can you enable exceptions in the `ndk-build` build? The instructions for doing so are in the link in the question, starting at _"To enable exceptions across your whole application in ndk-build,..."_ If you need RTTI as well instructions for that are in the next section.

Comment: @RichardCritten Of course I could. But as I wrote in my post I'd like to keep them disabled.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you I think this is the solution...